# CanvasVirtualControl ,Invalidate works as async and how to make it await?

Tags: uwp-xaml, win2d

What i have tried is?
My xaml Code:

```
 <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas">
   
    <Button Content="InvalidateParticularRegion" Height="100" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Top="0" Click="InvalidateParticularRegion"/>
</Canvas>
```

My c# code:

```
CanvasVirtualControl canvasVirtualControl;
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        canvasVirtualControl = new CanvasVirtualControl();
        canvasVirtualControl.Width = 1486;
        canvasVirtualControl.Height = 610;
        MyCanvas.Children.Add(canvasVirtualControl);
        Canvas.SetLeft(canvasVirtualControl, 0);
        Canvas.SetTop(canvasVirtualControl, 100);
        canvasVirtualControl.RegionsInvalidated += CanvasVirtualControl_RegionsInvalidated;
    }


    private void CanvasVirtualControl_RegionsInvalidated(CanvasVirtualControl sender, CanvasRegionsInvalidatedEventArgs args)
    {
        CanvasDrawingSession drawingSession;
        Rect rect = new Rect(args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Left, args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Top, args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Width, args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Height);
        Debug.WriteLine((args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Left + "   " + args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Top + "   " + args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Width + "   " +args.InvalidatedRegions[0].Height));
        using (drawingSession = sender.CreateDrawingSession(rect))
        {
            drawingSession.DrawRectangle((float)rect.X, (float)rect.Y, (float)rect.Width, (float)rect.Height, Colors.Green, 10);
        }
    }

    private void InvalidateParticularRegion(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        canvasVirtualControl.Invalidate(new Rect(1, 1, 100, 100));
        Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
        canvasVirtualControl.Invalidate(new Rect(200, 200, 150, 150));
        Debug.WriteLine("prem");
        canvasVirtualControl.Invalidate(new Rect(400, 200, 150, 150));
        Debug.WriteLine("kumar");
    }
```

Output:

Hello

prem

kumar

0.800000011920929   0.800000011920929   100   100

200   200   150.399993896484   150.399993896484

400   200   150.399993896484   150.399993896484

My doubt is,When I click the InvalidateParticularRegion button, Why the Invalidate() method of CanvasVirtualControl inside the click event fired after the three Debug.WriteLine().I think Invalidtae works like async.If it work Works like that, how to make it await?

Comment: By testing, when called the Invalidate() method, it will render internally and trigger the event after rendering. We can not control when the RegionsInvalidated can be triggered, so currently there is no method to wait Invalidate() method to complete and then do the next one.

Comment: Is there an other way?

Comment: Invalidate and RegionsInvalidated are not a whole, Invalidate is equivalent to sending a signal, we can’t control when RegionsInvalidated is raised.

Answer (score 0):

What result are you trying to achieve in your app?

Based on your sample, I suggest that you use the [CanvasAnimatedControl](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_UI_Xaml_CanvasAnimatedControl.htm) which refreshes at a regular interval.